# open source gossip-based membership protocol?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, distributed-algorithm

I am looking for a library which I can plug into a distributed application which implements any gossip-based membership protocol.

Such a library would allow me to send/receive membership lists, merge received membership lists, etc... Even better would be if the library implemented a protocol with performance O(logn) performance guarantees.

Does anyone know of any open source library like this? It doesn't need to meet all of the aforementioned requirements; even something partially implemented would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this on google code:

http://code.google.com/p/gossip-protocol-java/

I happen to stumble upon it yesterday whilst looking for java based gossip implementation. It's more a reference implementation for someone to build upon, but it gives the general idea, and after reading through the code you'll definitely be able to build your own or branch what's there to add any features you need.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Apache Zookeeper](http://hadoop.apache.org/zookeeper)?  I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for.

> ZooKeeper is a high-performance
>   coordination service for distributed
>   applications. It exposes common
>   services - such as naming,
>   configuration management,
>   synchronization, and group services -
>   in a simple interface so you don't
>   have to write them from scratch. You
>   can use it off-the-shelf to implement
>   consensus, group management, leader
>   election, and presence protocols.

C# bindings are also [available](http://github.com/ewhauser/zookeeper).

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at scalecube cluster swim and gossip protocol?

https://github.com/scalecube/scalecube-cluster